# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 error in sdk <= 29

Tags: java, android, mobile, sdk

I have got the error **java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0** in sdk 29 while it is working properly in sdk upper than 29
my test activity code is

```
          protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(testList.get(g_selected_cat_test_index).getTName());
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    progressDialog= new Dialog(TestActivity.this);
    progressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT  );
    dialogText =progressDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);
    dialogText.setText("loading data ...");
    progressDialog.show();
   
    testRView = findViewById(R.id.testRecyclerview);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layoutManager.setOrientation(RecyclerView.VERTICAL);
    testRView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
   loadTestNData(new MyCompleteListener() {
       @Override
       public void onSuccess() {
           DbQuery.loadMyScore(new MyCompleteListener() {
               @Override
               public void onSuccess() {
                   TestNAdapter adapter = new TestNAdapter(DbQuery.testNumList);
                   testRView.setAdapter(adapter);
                   progressDialog.dismiss();
               }

               @Override
               public void onFailure() {
                   Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this,"Something went wrong ! ploease try again later",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   progressDialog.dismiss();
               }
           });

       }

       @Override
       public void onFailure() {
           Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this,"Something went wrong ! ploease try again later",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           progressDialog.dismiss();

       }
   });

}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home)
    {
        TestActivity.this.finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

everything working fine in sdk upper than 30 and 30 but creating problem in sdk 29and lower
error is

```
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sarthak.mathadda1/com.sarthak.mathadda1.TestActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
   Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
at com.sarthak.mathadda1.TestActivity.onCreate(TestActivity.java:48)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
 at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
 at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)                                        
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:735at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

the error is i am getting when i run in android 10 sdk 29 while it is working properly in android 11 or higher

Comment: please provide the entire stacktrace. Also show a minimal example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: do you know how to read that stacktrace, where to check in your code? you don't show any line nrs, so it's pretty hard for us to figure out

Comment: I have got this line    `getSupportActionBar().setTitle(testList.get(g_selected_cat_test_index).getTName());`

Comment: so my guess is, this is giving the issue. testList.get(g_selected_cat_test_index). But if you know going to a newer version resolves the issue, why don't you? it may be a bug that was fixed

Comment: I have issues in android 10 only why it is working properly in androids 11,12,13 and 14

Comment: don't know, but as I said "it may be a bug that was fixed"